# Как создать модель используя receiver

Tags: django, веб-программирование, backend

Есть две модели : Project ( Проекты ) и Criteria ( критерии оценивания Проекта). Нужно, чтобы при создании проекта через форму, сразу с ним создавались и критерии к нему. Хочу сделать это через receiver, но вылетает ошибка **'Project' object has no attribute 'Criteria'**

#models.py

```
class Project(models.Model):
    user = ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=CASCADE)
    name = CharField(_("Название проекта"), max_length=150, db_index=True)
    site = URLField(_("Ссылка на сайт проекта"), max_length=200)
    description = TextField(_("Описание продукта/сервиса"))
    note = CharField(_("Примечание к проекту"), max_length=150, db_index=True)
    responsible = CharField(_("Ответственный"), max_length=150, db_index=True)
    data_create = DateTimeField(_("Время создания"), auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Criteria(models.Model):
    app = ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=CASCADE, default=None)
    science = BooleanField(_("Есть наука"), default=False)
    interesting = BooleanField(_("Интересный"), default=False)
    difficult = BooleanField(_("Сложный"), default=False)
    unclear = BooleanField(_("Непонятный"), default=False)
    repeat = BooleanField(_("Повтор"), default=False)

    @receiver(post_save, sender=Project)
    def create_criteria(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
        Criteria.objects.create(app=instance)

    @receiver(post_save, sender=Project)
    def save_criteria(sender, instance, **kwargs):
        instance.criteria.save()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Receiver не должен быть методом класса, так что его нужно вынести из под него

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Project) 
    def create_criteria(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
        Criteria.objects.create(app=instance).save()
```

Comment: отметьте как правильный ответ чтоли